# 1 always not match in Django re_path regular expression

Tags: python, django, regex

I try to create a dynamic path which accepts either null or positive integer.

For example:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/23

in url.py:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^my_url/(\s*|[0-9]{0,})$', views.my_function, name='my_function'),
]
```

in view.py:

```
def my_function(request, my_id):
    if my_id == '':
        #Do somthing
    else:
        #Do another somthing
```

Strange thing is:

followings passed in my test:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/2

http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/10

The only one that failed (meaning return to 404, no url found) is:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/1

why only '1' does not match? Is 1 treated specially in re_path function?

/****** Update ******/

It turns out that there is simply something wrong with my browser (might be a cookie issue). After I clean up and restart my browser, the regular expression works for 1 as well.

Comment: Do you use something like `get_object_or_404` in your `my_function`?

Comment: Wouldn't `r'my_url/(\d*)` do the same job?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: no, but for all other cases, the program will run into my_function. Only 1 directly broken (not even go into my_function in view.py)

Comment: @ Tim Roberts: Just tested it. Yes, this also works. But the same issue, 1 doesn't work. It go to 404 error

Comment: @codingsnake99: do you have other paths? Can you include these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update on your question explains that this is likely some caching mechanism in the browser.

I would however advise to split this up into two `paths`: one with an `<int:my_int>` parameter, and one without such parameter. These can both call the same view:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('my_url/', views.my_function, name='my_function'),
    path('my_url/<int:my_id>/', views.my_function,  name='my_function')
]
```

In the view, you then make `my_id` an optional parameter that resolves to `None` in case it is not called with this parameter:

```
def my_function(request, my_id=None):
    if my_id is None:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any advantage to splitting it into two paths rather than using one line with regex? Or it is just a matter of readability?

Comment: @codingsnake99: it is less likely that it contains bugs: usually clean code is less error prone code.